# Using trigonometric power formulas to derive an identity for $\cos^3(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, summation

I am practicing with manipulating sigma notation and binomial coefficients right now. I am using the formula given [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometricPowerFormulas.html) to derive the identity for $\cos^3(x)$

The identity for $\cos^3(x)$ is

$$\cos^3(x)=\dfrac{1}{4}[3\cos(x)+\cos(3x)]$$

Now, the formula for deriving the identity of $\cos^{2n+1}(x)$ is

$$\cos^{2n+1}(x)=\dfrac{1}{4^{n}}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n+1}{k}\cos[(2n+1-2k)x]$$

Let $n=1$

I have

$$\cos^{3}(x)=\dfrac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^{1}\binom{3}{0}\cos(3x)$$

$$=\cos^{3}(x)=\dfrac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^{1}2\cos(3x)$$

I know that a summation notation denotes:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}x_k=k_0+k_1+k_2+...k_n$$

But $k$ varnishes because I set it as $k=0$, so I think I am wrong there.

I think my calculation is clearly incorrect. Could you show me full works of how to arriving at the final identity using the power reduction formula?

Answer (score 0):

$$\cos^{2n+1}(x)=\frac{1}{4^{n}}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n+1}{k}\cos[(2n+1-2k)x]$$
if I plug $n=1$ becomes
$$\cos^3 x=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^1\binom{3}{k}\cos(3-2k)x$$
which is
$$\cos^3 x=\frac14\left(\cos 3x+3\cos x\right)$$

**edit**

I think I know what confuses you
$$\sum_{k=0}^1\binom{3}{k}\cos(3-2k)x$$
means that you sum the quantity when $k=0$ plus when $k=1$ like the following
$$\binom{3}{0}\cos(3-2\cdot 0)x+\binom{3}{1}\cos(3-2\cdot 1)x$$

Comment: I think what I did wrong is that I did not let the sum run from  $k=0$ to $n=1$, this is the meaning of the summation notation. Am I correct?

Comment: Read my edit @JamesWarthington

Comment: Ok, I got it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This is *way easier* with [Chebyshev polynomials](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheFirstKind.html).
From the property
$$T_n(\cos\theta)=\cos(n\theta)$$
We get
$$T_3(\cos\theta)=4\cos^3\theta-3\cos\theta=\cos(3\theta)$$
$$\cos^3\theta=\frac{\cos(3\theta)+3\cos\theta}{4}$$
Easy as pie if you understand the linked article.

Comment: The asker is confused about sum notation. I doubt he knows Chebychev polynomials. Or finds them way easier.

Comment: @K.defaoite I haven't learnt contour integration, so that is way over my head. I don't know how to take the integral.

Comment: @Oussema Fair point.